# How can I use apt instead of pkcon in KDE neon?

Tags: apt, kde, upgrade, plasma5, kde-neon

When I run `apt upgrade` I get the following message from KDE neon:

```
On KDE neon you should use `pkcon update` to install updates.
If you absolutely must use apt you do have to use dist-upgrade or full-upgrade in place of the upgrade command. [...]
Abort.
```

So the point is the **abort**.

Whatever KDE neon likes, I'd still like to use *apt*. Is there any way to still use it without a *full-upgrade*?

KDE: 4:5.15.5-0xneon+18.04+bionic+build48

Answer (score 7):

KDE neon's [FAQ page](https://neon.kde.org/faq) has this:

> KDE neon does continuous deployment of the latest KDE software which
>   means there are nearly always new versions of our software to update
>   to. We recommend using Plasma Discover's updater which appears in your
>   panel:
>
> If you prefer to use the command line you can use the pkcon command:
>
> ```
> pkcon refresh
> pkcon update
> ```
>
> This will install all new packages and uses the same PackageKit code
>   as Plasma Discover. Some uses of apt do not install new packages which
>   makes it less suitable for KDE neon.

It seems, based on the last sentence in the quoted material, the KDE neon developers believe that `apt upgrade` isn't suitable. To ensure users don't go that route, the KDE neon developers have somehow disabled `apt upgrade`. As suggested by the terminal output, you need to use `apt full-upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` if you don't want to use `pkcon` or *Discover*.

This is still the case after today's update to Plasma 5.16.

If the use of `apt upgrade` instead of `apt full-upgrade` is important to you, you can

- [file a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/) which will probably be closed with a WONTFIX or
- use another distribution such as Kubuntu 19.04 (with the [Kubuntu backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports)) which, more or less, keeps pace with KDE neon's Plasma updates but allows `apt upgrade`.

I, personally, have no issue with using `apt full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning to use `pkcon`. KDE Neon disables `apt upgrade` with good reason. `apt upgrade` won't actually update all of your packages, as KDE Neon distributes some packages which cannot be updated via `apt`. I am personally a huge fan of `apt`, but I just learned to use `pkcon` instead.

Comment: The problem is that when I want to install third party software that's not in the KDE Discover store, I often *must* use apt because the installation instructions (For Elements Matrix client for example, or Celestia) tell you to add a new entry into /etc/apt/sources.list.d and then apt install.

Is there some way to do this with pkcon? It seems to me that that command only installs software in Discover.

Comment: You can add new repositories with `apt-add-repository`, or by editing files yourself, and they will be installed with `pkcon` too. PackageKit uses `apt` as the backend in KDE Neon, so it gives you everything `apt` is doing plus more.

Comment: I'm running 5.20 and every now and then `pkcon` hangs on the `Running [===     ]` step. `apt full-upgrade` does the trick though.

Comment: Software is buggy.

Comment: @Caveman I have the same issue. Here's a bug report that I filed against KDE: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436390

Answer (score 0):

Remove package `neon-settings` or `neon-settings-2`

Or use command `sudo apt purge neon*`

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).